# dc.js with node.js server side

Tags: node.js, d3.js, dc.js

i want rendering dcCharts on the server with node.js. I have an example with d3.js and node.js. But my code doesnt work. Im a beginner with node.js, hopefully yoe have an idea ?

The code for d3.js with node.js:[example](https://gist.github.com/mef/7044786)

and here what i try with dc.js and node.js:

```
var d3 = require('d3')
, dc = require('dc')
, jsdom = require('jsdom')
, fs = require('fs')
, htmlStub = '<html><head></head><body><div id="dataviz-container"></div><script    src="js/d3.v3.min.js"></script></body></html>'

jsdom.env({
features : { QuerySelector : true }
, html : htmlStub
, done : function(errors, window) {
// this callback function pre-renders the dataviz inside the html document, then    export result into a static file

var el = window.document.querySelector('#dataviz-container')
, body = window.document.querySelector('body')

var data = [
    {date: "12/27/2012", http_404: 2, http_200: 190, http_302: 100},
    {date: "12/28/2012", http_404: 2, http_200: 10, http_302: 100},
    {date: "12/29/2012", http_404: 1, http_200: 300, http_302: 200},
    {date: "12/30/2012", http_404: 2, http_200: 90, http_302: 0},
    {date: "12/31/2012", http_404: 2, http_200: 90, http_302: 0},
    {date: "01/01/2013", http_404: 2, http_200: 90, http_302: 0},
    {date: "01/02/2013", http_404: 1, http_200: 10, http_302: 1},
    {date: "01/03/2013", http_404: 2, http_200: 90, http_302: 0},
    {date: "01/04/2013", http_404: 2, http_200: 90, http_302: 0},
    {date: "01/05/2013", http_404: 2, http_200: 90, http_302: 0},
    {date: "01/06/2013", http_404: 2, http_200: 200, http_302: 1},
    {date: "01/07/2013", http_404: 1, http_200: 200, http_302: 100}
    ];

var ndx = crossfilter(data);

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%m/%d/%Y").parse;

data.forEach(function(d) {
d.date = parseDate(d.date);
d.total= d.http_404+d.http_200+d.http_302;
});

var dateDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return d.date;});
var hits = dateDim.group().reduceSum(function(d) {return d.total;});

var hitslineChart  = dc.pieChart('dataviz-container');
hitslineChart
.width(500).height(200)
.transitionDuration(500)
.colors(d3.scale.category10())
.radius(90)
.dimension(dateDim)
.group(hits);

dc.renderAll();





// save result in an html file, we could also keep it in memory, or export the       interesting fragment into a database for later use
var svgsrc = window.document.innerHTML
fs.writeFile('index.html', svgsrc, function(err) {
if(err) {
console.log('fehler beim speichern', err)
} else {
console.log('Datei wurde gespeichert!')
}
})  
} // end jsDom done callback
})
```

I think `var hitslineChart  = dc.pieChart('dataviz-container');` is wrong.

---

I change know my htmlStub and dc.pieChart:

```
var hitslineChart  = dc.pieChart('el');

htmlStub = '<html><head></head><body><div id="dataviz-container"></div></script><script type="text/javascript" src="js/d3.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="js/crossfilter.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="js/dc.js"></script></body></html>'
```

Unfortunately, I still get this error:

```
C:\Users\kasse\Code\node-modules\dc\dc.js:2366
    var _colors = d3.scale.category20c();

ReferenceError: d3 is not defined
at Object.dc.colorChart (C:\Users\kasse\Code\node_modules\dc\dc.js:2366:19)
at Object.dc.pieChart (C:\Users\kasse\Code\node_modules\dc\dc.js:2971:31)
at jsdom.env.done (C:\Users\kasse\Code\pre_render.js:44:25)
at C:\Users\kasse\Code\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom.js:255:9
at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:499:11)
at startup (node.js:119:16)
at node.js:902:3
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Does anyone have an idea? I desperately need help ... thank you

Comment: http://bigsnarf.wordpress.com/2012/12/28/multi-dimensional-charting-built-to-work-natively-with-crossfilter-rendered-using-d3-js/

Comment: Try this blog post shows d3 / dc and cross filter on node js. http://bigsnarf.wordpress.com/2012/12/28/multi-dimensional-charting-built-to-work-natively-with-crossfilter-rendered-using-d3-js/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make d3 a global variable inside your module:

```
global.d3 = d3;

... chart rendered here
dc.renderAll();

    var svgsrc = window.document.querySelector('#bubbleChart');
    fs.writeFile('chart.svg', svgsrc.innerHTML, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('error saving document', err);
        } else {
            console.log('The file was saved!');
        }
    });
```

Then convert the svg to a png using command line tools like ImageMagick. See this post for an example:
http://eng.wealthfront.com/2011/12/converting-dynamic-svg-to-png-with.html

Comment: unfortunately I did not get a chart at the end....have you an idea how i get a png-Chart at the end?

Comment: You existing code should have produced an html file. You could manually process the file by viewing it with your web browser. If you want a more automated process, then you can save the output as a .svg file instead of HTML. The code would look like the code I added above.

Comment: Hi Steve, if i open it with my browser. I get only a whithe page. Something wrong there

Comment: i just get undefied in the result html file

Answer (score 1):

Your htmlStub is wrong, it has an extra `</script>` in; that is almost certainly causing node.js to fail to run it.

It should (probably) be:

```
htmlStub = '<html><head></head><body><div id="dataviz-container"></div><script type="text/javascript" src="js/d3.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="js/crossfilter.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="js/dc.js"></script></body></html>';
```

Errors like this are more obvious if you break up the strings:

```
   htmlStub  = '<html><head></head><body>';
   htmlStub += '<div id="dataviz-container"></div>';
   htmlStub += '<script type="text/javascript" src="js/d3.js"></script>';
   htmlStub += '<script type="text/javascript" src="js/crossfilter.js"></script>';
   htmlStub += '<script type="text/javascript" src="js/dc.js"></script>';
   htmlStub += '</body></html>';
```